# Setting up a CDBMS server

Tags: installation

I read something in wikipedia about CDBMS. I have no idea how to setup a CDBMS server!

Is it comparable to how I am currently using mysql?

I have some extremely large databases and I want to convert my dataset into CDBMS and test my codes with the new database. What are some things I need to be aware of before I start doing this, and how will the new code be different, if at all, from my existing code?

I don't have any more details. My supervisor asked me to check if CDBMS is a better way for analyzing a large dataset. So, I just wanted to setup a CDBMS and convert my dataset to it.

Answer (score 3):

A CDBMS is a specialized database for handling queries like ["show everything that is related to x"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_database#Advantages_and_Disadvantages_of_the_CDBMS). Unless that is what you want (and unless you don't want all the features of a traditional RDBMS like MySQL), you don't want a CDBMS.

Comment: I am analyzing some data for an online social network website which is really heavy. I wanted to convert my dataset into CDBMS to check if it is good for the analyzing.

Comment: It depends what sort of analysing. Typical query? If it is something like "list the people with (free format) status 'single'" then maybe you should look into it further.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment - the point is whether you are looking for the same data across multiple tables or not.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean a:

> A Correlation database is a database management system (DBMS) that is data model independent and designed to efficiently handle unplanned, ad hoc queries in an analytical system environment. It was developed in 2005 by database architect Joseph Foley, whose background includes more than 30 years in data warehousing and business intelligence research and development work across a variety of industries.
>   Unlike relational database management systems, which use a records-based storage approach, or column-oriented databases which use a column-based storage method, a correlation database uses a value-based storage (VBS) architecture in which each unique data value is stored only once and an auto-generated indexing system maintains the context for all values.[1]

snipped from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_database)

Why don't you start with "where did you hear about it" and "what makes you think this is something you need" and "what are your goals for using a CDBMS?

Comment: Thanx, I read that in wikipedia. I have some extremely large databases and I want to convert my dataset into CDBMS and test my codes with the new database.

Comment: I posted from wikipedia because I didn't know it was, so I figured others also wouldn't know what it was.

Comment: @AliBZ if you would be _so kind_ as to update your question with that information, and give us some more details. I will help you out just a little, by adding some information for you. You can edit your question right underneath the original question.

Comment: You are right, I should mention that. You know, I don't have any more details. My supervisor asked me to check if CDBMS is a better way for analyzing a large dataset. So, I just wanted to setup a CDBMS and convert my dataset to it.